# Using Calc button and radiobutton listeners together

Tags: java, swing, button, radio-button, listeners

I'm working on a project that calculates the price of a call based on how many minutes one talked for and the time of day of the call. Everything works except the Calculate button. I'm not sure how to make it so when the Calculate button is clicked, it looks for which radio button is selected and performs the appropriate equation. I have tried using loops but it isn't working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class RateChargeGUI extends JFrame
{
private JPanel panel;  
private JLabel messageLabel; //message to the  user
private JTextField timeTextField; //user inputs time of call in minutes
private JPanel Buttons;
private JRadioButton DayTimeButton;  //declares a new radio button called DayTimeButton
private JRadioButton EveningButton; //declares a new radio button called EveningButton
private JRadioButton Off_PeakButton; //declares a new radio button called Off_PeakButton
private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup; //places the buttons in a group
private JButton exitButton; 
private JButton calcButton;
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 300; //window width
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300; //window height

/**
Constructor 
*/

public RateChargeGUI ()
{
    //sets the text for the title bar
    setTitle("Call Prices");
    //sets the size of the window
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //build a panel that will be added to the frame
    buildPanel();
    buildButtons();

    //add the panel to the frame
    add(panel);
    add(Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //display the window
    setVisible(true);
}


//The buildPanel method adds a label, text field, and the buttons to the panel.

private void buildPanel()
{
messageLabel = new JLabel(" Enter Number of minutes "); //label left of the text box telling the user what to do.
timeTextField = new JTextField(10); //text field that accepts the duration of the call
DayTimeButton = new JRadioButton("Day Time"); // radio buttons for the time of day that the call is made
EveningButton = new JRadioButton("Evening");
Off_PeakButton = new JRadioButton("Off_Peak");


//add and group the radio buttons

radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
radioButtonGroup.add(DayTimeButton);
radioButtonGroup.add(EveningButton);
radioButtonGroup.add(Off_PeakButton);

//action listeners for the radio buttons that make it possible to select one of them
//DayTimeButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener ());
//EveningButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener ());
//Off_PeakButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener ());

//create a panel and add the components to it. such as the label telling the user to enter the number of minutes
//or the radio buttons
panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(messageLabel);
panel.add(timeTextField);
panel.add(DayTimeButton);
panel.add(EveningButton);
panel.add(Off_PeakButton);

Buttons = new JPanel();
add(Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
private void buildButtons()
{
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

    exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener ());
    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener ());

    Buttons.add(calcButton);
    Buttons.add(exitButton);
}
/**
Private inner class that handles the event when the user clicks one of the radio buttons.
*/

private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String input; //holds user input
        double result = 0.0; //holds the conversion
        input = timeTextField.getText(); //enables the text field to accept text

        //Determine which radio button was selected and perform a mathmatical equation based on which button was selected.
        //6AM-6PM
        if (e.getSource() == DayTimeButton)
        {
            result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.20;
        }
        //6PM-12AM
        else if (e.getSource() == EveningButton)
        {
            result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.12;
        }
        //12AM-6AM
        else if (e.getSource() == Off_PeakButton)
        {
            result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.04;
        }
        if (DaytimeButton.is
        //display the ammount that it will cost
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The call price is: $ " + result);
    }
}
private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
//calls the ratechargegui class. The RateChargeGUI class was build above and is now being called.
public static void main(String[] args)// stringargs[] allows the program to accept arguments.
    {
    new RateChargeGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile? `if (DaytimeButton.is` is a syntax error. Also, *but it isn't working* tells us nothing. What are your current results? What are your expected results? How do your current results differ from your expected results?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What are you trying to do near  
**if (DaytimeButton.is**

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some variable are correct, other are not. Be consistent!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any addActionListener() methods in your code for the different buttons pertaining to hours of the day. If you want the event-handler to work, each radio button must have an actionListener attached. So, you could do this somewhere:

```
DayTimeButton.addActionListener(CalcButtonListener);
EveningButton.addActionListener(CalcButtonListener);
Off_PeakButton.addActionListener(CalcButtonListener);
```

Also, in Java, variable names need to be camelCase. Class/Interface names can start with capital letters, but not variables.

If you don't need to process the event that happens when one of the radio buttons is clicked, but just need the state of a radio button, try using method isSelected(). Your tests in actionPerformed could look something like this:

```
if (DaytimeButton.isSelected()) {
    // do stuff for this button
}
else if (EveningButton.isSelected()) {
    // do stuff for this button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply this listener only to calcButton, it is always going to be the event source. You have to check which radio button is selected when the action is performed.

```
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String input; //holds user input
    double result = 0.0; //holds the conversion
    input = timeTextField.getText(); //enables the text field to accept text

    // Determine which radio button was selected and perform a mathmatical equation based on which button was selected.
    //6AM-6PM
    if (DayTimeButton.isSelected()) {
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.20;
    }
    //6PM-12AM
    else if (EveningButton.isSelected()) {
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.12;
    }
    //12AM-6AM
    else if (Off_PeakButton.isSelected()) {
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.04;
    }

    //display the ammount that it will cost
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The call price is: $ " + result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have loops for this. As others have directed, you can use

```
   isSelected()
```

method when checking the selection of your radio buttons.

**Note**
However note these.

1. Whenever you expect an input from a user, before invoking the methods inside your logic do a textfield validation. Now for your instance you should check the input validity (empty input, letter input, etc) at once when the Caculate button is clicked.
2. When working with double, your output can have lots of decimal places. So better to format your output  before showing them to your uses.
3. Follow java naming conventions. Use "eveningButton", "dayTimeButton" for variables as @Daniel.Schroeder emphasize. At the same time use meaningful variable for components. For an instance you can use "dayTimeRadioBtn" so you know that later this is regarding your radio button not the button.